# Python Pulp Linear Programming Min Max range

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, pulp

I have below code snippet - which is essentially a constraint in my LP problem that I am trying to solve. How can I put this in a single line with a min max range?

```
prob += lpSum([base[i] * id_vars[i] for i in ID]) >= 33, "P1_34_Min_Base"
prob += lpSum([base[i] * id_vars[i] for i in ID]) <= 37, "P2_37_Max_Base"
```

essentially what I want to be able to do is:

```
prob += lpSum([base[i] * id_vars[i] for i in ID]) between 33 and 37, "P1_Base"
```

any help would be awesome. thanks

Comment: One way would be to create a variable `y` with bounds 33 and 37 and then introduce an equality constraint: `y=sum(i, base[i]*id_vars[i])`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally I think what you got is fine.  not sure this will work but you can try

```
prob += lpSum([base[i] * id_vars[i] for i in ID]) - 33 <= 4
```

this assumes your vars have a lower bound of 0